# KeyError while accessing multi index dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have the following dataframe having "Location" and "Name" as the index.

```
Location  Name   Cost   Item Purchased                
Store 1   Chris  22.5   Dog Food
          Kevyn   2.5   Kitty Litter
Store 2   Vinod   5.0   Bird Seed
```

I can access `df.loc["Store 1"]`
But `df.loc["Store 1"]["Kevyn"]` is giving me KeyError. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: pass a tuple `df.loc[("Store 1","Kevyn")]`, see the docs http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using some incorrect chained indexing here, where you want to be indexing both levels of the MultiIndex with something like

```
df.loc['Store 1', 'Kevyn']
```

See [*Basic indexing on axis with MultiIndex*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/advanced.html#basic-indexing-on-axis-with-multiindex) in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a tuple:

```
In [100]:
df.loc[('Store 1', 'Kevyn'),:]

Out[100]:
Cost                       2.5
Item Purchased    Kitty Litter
Name: (Store 1, Kevyn), dtype: object
```

The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index) detail how to index

Comment: In fact, you should use ```df.loc[('Store 1', 'Kevyn'),:]``` in order to avoid misinterpretations, cf. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers